# associative container in c++, that can store duplicate key and value and also give common intersection between the keys

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, containers

I'm trying to implement a social network class using stl. Each user can have parameters like name,age,gender,friends and hobbies. I have a particular function called searchUsersByHobbies which takes a set of hobbies as input and returns all the users which have the same hobbies.

Could you suggest a way to store the hobbies and user, so that this operation can happen with the least complexity

Comment: Did you consider to use a combination of [c++ standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)?

Comment: You can't use a single C++ standard library (not [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), that's something different) container or structure for this. As mentioned you have to use multiple containers and your own structures. Unless you skip the requirement of using standard C++ containers and go for a "proper" database instead.

Comment: A social network is implemented as an undirected weighted graph. You can try to imitate the implementation using various STL containers, but I don't think you'll get the efficiency just from that. Unfortunately there's no ``std::facebook`` container yet.

Comment: You need a database, not C++ containers.

Comment: According to the question, i am required to use STL containers to replicate the behavior, would appreciate if you could suggest a combination of containers also